# How to use fancybox/magnific-popup for video in custom phtml in magento2

Tags: magento2, iframe, fancybox

For a normal HTML file, we import the js and CSS files of the fancybox/magnific-popup.
And use script like the example I'm using magnific popup

```
$('.test-popup').magnificPopup({
    type:'iframe'
});
```

It's working fine but when comes to magento2. I added the CSS and js file in web and initialized in requirejs-config.js by referring this answer

[How to display fancybox popup when page load in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172416/how-to-display-fancybox-popup-when-page-load-in-magento2)

but audio-only playing I can't see video/iframe.
What's the cause and solution thank you

Comment: Just placing CSS file in web is not enough. You need to include it in your layout file head.

Comment: Yes, Included in default_head_block.xml like, <css src="path"/> It also loading.but not working. Thank you